# Monitor that can play video files straight from external hard drive, without internet or wifi?

Tags: monitors, video

Can someone recommend a monitor that can play video files straight from an external hard drive, preferably along a USB to USB connection and preferably in various formats (certainly including .mp4, preferably also .flv and .mkv), and that does not need also to be connected to the internet or a laptop or use wifi. Ideally I would like something that does not receive any kind of TV signal and therefore does not require a TV licence to keep. I realise a CPU is required in order to stream the file to the monitor, but I'm wondering whether you can get this built into the box with the monitor and without requiring a separate third device.

To summarise: I need a screen that I can put on the wall so that when I want to watch one of the films I've got on an external drive, I can throw a USB cable from the external drive to the monitor, throw an audio cable from the monitor to some speakers, and sit back and watch the film. (And I don't want to watch TV or do anything on the internet or using wireless.)

Comment: Just to curb questions and bad recommendations on behalf of the person asking the question: Some nations require you have a license to own and operate a television, such as Great Britain.   The United States doesn't require this, so many readers may be confused by the question.   The use-case here is for a basic computer-monitor all-in-one without a TV tuner.

Comment: perhaps you could purchase a commercial large screen monitor that has no tuner  .... Visio apparently makes tunerless TVs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like [this](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/cty/pdp/spd/inspiron-22-3277-aio/fdcw22ipun104s?cid=310435&st=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuKm5wI-r3AIV1jaBCh1WdA6JEAQYAyABEgLRlPD_BwE&lid=5860376&VEN1=snajNacpJ,183144151912,901pdb6671,c,,FDCW22IPUN104S&VEN2=,&dgc=st&dgseg=dhs&acd=1230980731501410&VEN3=235204297008936848), where the computer is an all-in-one unit.  This pricing isn't too bad considering what it is, and you don't have a ton of options.  Note that it doesn't have video inputs for the monitor portion of the unit, so it does not classify as a television.   This model also has a touch-screen, so no need for a keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Thanks for this, which I've accepted. I wouldn't mind if the device had video inputs to the monitor: they might come in useful some time, and in Britain they don't require having a TV licence. But the main thing is to play video files saved on the external hard drive, using USB.